# location_rel for ios appium

Tags: ios, ruby, appium

I use appium inspector and seeing ios app element I am interested has a location as {75,185.5} However, when I use location_rel method, I am getting {:x => “0.0 /375.0”, :y =>“0.0 /667.0”}.

Can some one please suggest how I can get the right location for the target object which is {75,185.5}

[image]

In addition , I have tried to use xpath to locate the element , then try out the name, text ,and location_rel property.  and I am getting the same result both name and text return "", and location_rel return

```
[4] pry(main)> like.location_rel
OpenStruct {
:x => "0.0 / 375.0",
:y => "0.0 / 667.0"
}
```

Comment: assuming you are looking at the centre `Point` of the element for the location in appium inspector, I believe the element seems to be not existing while you are trying to locate it, since not just the `location` but even the `width` and `height` of the element equals `0` in your case.

Comment: Could you share the appium screenshot of the same element and your piece of code to find its `location_rel` for more understanding.

Comment: @nullpointer,  thank you for your info, here is the screenshot. for arc info,please refer to this screen shot: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9qMhFFQ_RhwaWZQUFVVTXpNNlE/view?usp=sharing                                                                                                         for appium inspector: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9qMhFFQ_RhwVjU4ZTZicFpXdHM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: are you able to read the text of the `comment` in your code or perform any other action?

Comment: @nullpointer here is what I see : [24] pry(main)> comment.size
{
     :width => 0,
    :height => 0
}
[25] pry(main)> comment.name
""                                                                                                                 [27] pry(main)> comment.location
{
    :x => 0,
    :y => 0
}

Comment: so both name and text attribute return "".  and for size I got width => 0 and height =>0.  for location : x=>0 , and :y=>0.

Comment: seems like the element is not accessed correctly using the locator

Comment: So the solution will have to have the element accessbility to be true and the visible to be true?

Comment: based on the inspector or arc page , all I know about the element is "UIAImange, and name is : likes.png"

Comment: could you try accessing the element using XPATH and also share the details in the question itself.

Comment: @nullpointer  here is the xpath info I got from arc:                                                  [1] pry(main)> xpath("//UIAApplication[1]/UIAWindow[1]/UIATableView[1]/UIATableCell[1]/UIAImage[1]")

#<Selenium::WebDriver::Element:0x5ed2a75eed61590 id="0">
       [2] pry(main)> like= xpath("//UIAApplication[1]/UIAWindow[1]/UIATableView[1]/UIATableCell[1]/UIAImage[1]")

#<Selenium::WebDriver::Element:0x..fcfdc81625f8a2548 id="1">
   [3] pry(main)> like.name
""
   [4] pry(main)> like.location_rel
OpenStruct {
    :x => "0.0 / 375.0",
    :y => "0.0 / 667.0"
}
   [5] pry(main)> like.text
""

Comment: Could you update this in question please

Comment: @nullpointer thank you for the instruction, update is done.